# How to publish a library that can have browser-specific code but should run on NodeJs too

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollup

I have a library (as an npm package) that can be consumed in NodeJs and in a browser. It currently output as an UMD file. However, part of the library will now be browser specific (it will export React components).

How should I do this? Should I exclude browser specific files, let's say maybe all `*.tsx` files from the NodeJs output?

What else should i take into account?

I would really prefer if I don't need to create two different libraries, one with the pure JS code and the other with the browser-specific one.

Comment: Could those react component be used on the server as well?

Comment: Yes, maybe. Not the most important need, but yes if possible

Comment: Then I wouldn't distinguish between "is the library used in the browser or in node.js", but rather it should try to load the `react` library and if installed it should provide the react-specific part. (Or it should just always provide that part in a separate module that can be imported or not)